# Add Camera Usage Description for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, devexpress, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I was trying to add Camera Usage Description for my devextreme cordova mobile project but testing it in ios device only get generic message.

I tried adding this code in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" onload="true" />
<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist" overwrite="true">
    <string>We are using a camera to enable you to upload pictures of documents</string>
</config-file>

<config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist" overwrite="true">
   <string>We are using your pohoto library to enable you to download and save pictures of documents</string>
</config-file>
```

I tried the suggestion on this link
[Build Custom Application Template](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T590025/add-nscamerausagedescription-and-nsphotolibraryusagedesciption-to-multi-channel-app)

But upon building native package in ios I get error.

> Error build iOS package: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer

Can anyone help me on this? Or do you have any suggestions creating Camera Usage Description without creating custom application template for devexpress?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code in your config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="1.4.1" >
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="We are using a camera to enable you to upload pictures of documents" />

    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="We are using your pohoto library to enable you to download and save pictures of documents" />
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This is new plugin which I have to [Build a  Custom Application Template](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T590025/add-nscamerausagedescription-and-nsphotolibraryusagedesciption-to-multi-channel-app) which I am having error when I build a native package.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your iOS project .plist under "Privacy - Camera Usage Description"

Comment: But the project does not have .plist file.